# Why is my EPS from Illustrator so large?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save, file-size, eps

I have a logo file in Illustrator CC that is very simple, only 2 colors, some outlined text and 2 arrow shapes. For some reason the file size is over 2MB. The colors used are white and cyan (C=100 M=0 Y =0 K=0). I feel like the file size is absurd. What am I doing wrong when saving?

Here is the dialog box with the options that were there by default.

[image: Saving Settings]

[image: Logo with paths]

Comment: What happens when you uncheck the "Embed Fonts" and "CMYK"?  Does the image size change, at all?

Comment: No, it didn't make a difference at all, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I suspect this may have more to do with the artwork than the save options. What may *seem* simple, may not actually be simple when flattened for the EPS format.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of illustrator? (feel free to watermark it for privacy)

Comment: Thanks, I agree, I just can't imagine what about the artwork it is and if there's a way to simplify it.
There are 44 characters and 2 arrows. The characters are text that has been outlined. Could that increase size?

Comment: Edited my post. Showing the paths around the logo.

Comment: hmm.. does seem fairly straight-forward. I'd try saving as an Illustrator 8 EPS file and see if the file size is smaller (I'm guessing it will be dramatically).

Comment: Thanks again. That got it down to 1.3M... helps but still a mystery to me.

Comment: How big is your artboard? Are you making the file size like 10in instead of 1in? Making the canvas smaller would make a slight difference.

Comment: not even 200px wide....

Comment: Wait but... how small would you expect this to be? 2mb for a vector logo sounds about right. Not sure why this is a concern? Anyway another thing to try is to resave the file over itself. In some cases this can reduce the filesize.

Comment: Lucian, only because the other logos we have on file are smaller I thought I was doing something wrong, but perhaps I'm freaking out over nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a bit of testing.....

I set up some basic shapes and outlined text similar to your file.

[image]

Ran the **default action to Delete all Unused items**.

[image]

This deletes all unused swatches, symbols, styles, brushes, etc. and can have an effect on file size.

Saved as an AICC EPS. The *best* I got was a 1MB file. I would guess that the additional 1MB you are seeing is due to the unused panel items. Run that action and try resaving. Before deleting the unused items I do see approximately a 1.9MB EPS file.

Then I saved the file to AICS6 and opened it there.

Ran the delete unused item action and saved as an **AICS6 EPS**... file size **400k**.

[image]

Same *exact file*. The only difference is version if AI in use.

**It would appear as though AICC merely saves larger EPS files. You would need to ask Adobe why.**

The *only* way I was able to get a decent EPS file size using AICC2017 was to save to an **Ai8 EPS file**. This resulted in a ~250k document.

[image]

Now the AI8 format throws away *a lot* more data, especially metadata, than newer EPS formats. It's feasible that the newer formats are embedding additional PDF compatibility, color profiles, etc. Only Adobe would be aware of the *actual* variations in their EPS file formats.

> Just *commentary*...... Note that I, personally, **always** save EPS files to AI8 format. I've yet to see *any* reason to use a newer EPS format if EPS is needed. But then, I haven't been an XPress user for many years. Last I saw XPress didn't work with .ai files. In addition, I dislike the CC versions of AI and also *prefer* to work in CS6 as much as possible in spite of the issues it sometimes has. Add VectorScribe to AICS6.... and it's pretty much on par with CC2017 in my experience.

Comment: Newer adobe eps files have quite large handling functions for color. If one wants to get rid of all the extra bells and whistles then that scene can probably be ran into less than a kilobyte if one wanted to skip all the handlers.

Comment: Metis, thanks so much for putting all this effort!!! Wow, so kind of you. Let me try those methods.

Comment: Ran the action, it's 940KB which seems really reasonable. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to copy your example as closely as possible:

[image: Blatant Copy]

Document dimensions are 400x220. I was able to save an Illustrator CC EPS of this graphic at 490kb using the following settings:

[image: EPS Export]